# 18650 battery holder reliability

Tags: batteries

I am building a 4S8P battery pack and wonder if battery holders would be useful.

I find the 4S battery holder shown below to be nice, but am concerned about its current carrying capacity as I have a 8P configuration.
[image]

Another way to hold the batteries would be to use the [battery spacers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PWC8C6C). However are there similar battery holders as the one in picture that could potentially be more reliable? Hope someone can throw in some suggestions :)

Comment: I don't understand your current capacity concern, just solder some thicker gauge wires at the terminals if it actually worries you. However, The battery holders work just fine.

Comment: Those springs get bloody hot and melt the plastic at a few amps...

Comment: How many amps are you pulling?

Comment: @BrianDrummond that's exactly what i suspect....

Comment: @DKNguyen ~4.5A, maximum 8A

Comment: 8A out a single assembly does seem to be a bit much. Even if the 22AWG lead wires, it would be possible but pushing it. But the steel contact springs are the bigger issue. You can get aluminum versions, you know? But pricey. http://keyelco.com/userAssets/file/M65p20.pdf

Comment: The weak point would be whatever insulating material is used to separate the contacts from the body, but at least the body would act as a heatsink for it.

Comment: @YumekaMengjiaLYU that's exactly what I've seen. I rarely swear but it burnt my fingers.

Answer (score 0):

There exists aluminum battery holders where the only thermal weak spot is the insulating washer between the contact and the body. The washer is a glass-filled resin which should be better than the material the regular carrier is made out of, and also gets the benefit of the aluminum body heatsinking it. A bit pricey though.

Get versions where you add your own lead wires.

http://keyelco.com/userAssets/file/M65p20.pdf
[image]